# Проблемы с шифровкой файла

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, qt5, шифрование

Недавно я уже задавал несколько вопросов по моей программе-шифровщику, но теперь у меня появился новый (уже окончательный) вопрос. Дело в том, что последний этап моей программы - шифрование файлов с помощью *XOR*. Мой алгоритм прост:

1. Беру файл (через контекстное окно проводника).
2. Создаю *QBitArray* для уже взятого файла и помещаю его туда.
3. Беру путь и имя для нового файла (как в 1-ом).
4. Создаю *QBitArray*, вмещающий в себя пароль.
5. По 1 байту применяю операцию *XOR*.
6. Сохраняю результат.

В итоге зашифрованное изображение *PNG* не открылось. Однако не открылось оно и после расшифровки! А именно: *"Фатальная ошибка при чтении файла изображения формата PNG:I[D4][8B][E5]: invalid chunk type"*.

Привожу код программы и подписанный скриншот:

Код (нажатие кнопок "открыть" и "сохранить"):

```
#include "file.h"
#include "ui_file.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>

QByteArray opened;

File::File(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::File)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

File::~File()
{
    delete ui;
}

void File::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    opened.clear();
    QString pass = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Выберите файл: ", "", "");
    QFile file(pass);
    ui->textEdit->append(pass);
    if ((file.exists())&&(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)))
    {
        opened = file.readAll();
        file.close();
    }
}

void File::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QByteArray key = text.toUtf8();
    for (int i = 0; i < opened.length(); i ++)
    {
        opened [i] = key [i % key.length()] xor opened [i];
    }
    QString pass = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0, "Выберите имя и путь файла: ", "", "");
    QFile file(pass);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        file.write(opened);
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Вы читаете бинарный файл как текстовый (`file.readLine`). Не надо так.

Comment: @free_ze, а как?

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, [`readAll`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, и не надо читать файл при выборе. Вдруг я(как пользователь) случайно тыкну на какое-нибудь полуторачасовое 4k видео. Читайте в кнопке "сохранить". И не весь, а по кускам, при помощи [`read`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read)(вдруг я тыкну в полуторачасовое 4k видео намеренно)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, не помогло =(

Comment: Что такое opened? Какой у него тип?

Comment: Это QByteArray, хранящий в себе файл.

Comment: В вопросе весь код, смотрите на здоровье ;)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, нет - я иду по байтам везде.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, займитесь отладкой. Начните с `QByteArray data = readFile(); writeFile(data);`. Небольшими шагами добавляйте функциональность, проверяя результат на каждом шаге.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, скорее всего ошибка находится в алгоритме шифрования - я проверял, у исходного и конечного файла один и тот же вес, что и должно быть.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, теперь [проверьте](https://www.diffnow.com/) содержимое

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, а вообще говорю вам еще раз. Сделайте сначала программу, которая просто перезаписывает файл. Потом сделайте данным из файла два раза `xor 42`. Потом зашейте в коде ключ. Потом вычитайте ключ из поля ввода. А какой-то момент файл перестанет открываться. Будет понятно что именно не работает. Кстати, если бы вы так делали, ваш косяк с `readLine` выплыл бы в самом начале

Comment: Неумение разбивать задачу на мелкие и отлаживать свои программы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, дело в невнимательности. Если Вы посмотрите на скриншот, то увидите, что я считывал в строку-ключ не текст из *textEdit'а* с паролем, а из *textEdit'а* с путем к файлу. Естественно, я сохранял исходный и промежуточный файл в разных местах, из-за чего "пароль" различался. И теперь все хорошо работает)))